# can we convert a raster image in to vector image?

Tags: images

i have designed a logo in photoshop but it has affected the quality of image and its pixels are not clear when i zoom the image really far, its looks pixelated.i have increased the size of image also increased its resolution to make image quality better but can't do it well. now i want to convert it in to vector image with the help of illustrator to improve the quality of image. can i do this?if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the logo it's impossible to tell how well it would work, but Illustrator has an auto trace feature that could help get you started. However, a logo is too important to leave up to auto trace. You should probably rebuild it properly from scratch.